# Creating (seeding) large dictionaries efficiently in Python

Tags: python, performance, search, dictionary

I have a long (500K+ rows) two column spreadsheet that looks like this:

```
Name    Code
1234    A
1234    B
1456    C
4556    A
4556    B
4556    C
...
```

So there is an element (with a Name) that can have a number of Codes. But instead of one row per code, I would like to a list of all codes that occur for each element. What I want is a dictionary like this:

```
{"1234":["A","B"],"1456":["C"],"4556":["A","B","C"] ...]}
```

What I have tried is this (and I'm not including the file reading syntax).

```
    codelist = {}
    for row in rows:
        name,code = well.split()
        if name in codelist.keys():
            codelist[name].append(code)
        else:
            codelist[name] = [code]
```

This creates the right output but progress becomes incredibly slow. So I've tried priming my dictionary with keys:

```
allnames = [.... list of all the names ...]
codelist = dict.fromkeys(allnames)

for row in rows:

    name,code = well.split()
    if codelist[name]:
        codelist[name].append(code)
    else:
        codelist[name] = [code]
```

This is dramatically faster, and my question is why? Doesn't the program each time still have to search all the keys in the dict? Is there another way to speed up the dict search that doesn't include traversing a tree?

Interesting is the error I get when I use the same conditional check as before (if name in codelist.keys():) after priming my dictionary.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File .... 
    codelist[name].append(code)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Now, there is a key but no list to append to. So I use `codelist[name]` which is `<NoneType>` as well and appears to work. What does it mean when `mydict["primed key"]` is `<NoneType>` ?`enter code here`

Comment: @AC, sorry - cut/paste from IDLE... that was supposed to be {}. I've edited the post.

Comment: don't know exactly, but you are checking in codelist.keys(), which will create either a list or a view, while you could do 'name in codelist' and just do the lookup directly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The former one is slower because `.keys()` has to create a list of all keys in memory first and then the `in` operator performs a search on it. So, it is an [`O(N)`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#list) search for each line from the text file, hence it is slow.

On the other hand a simple [`key in dict`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#set) search takes `O(1)` time.

> dict.fromkeys(allnames)

The default value assigned by `dict.fromkeys` is `None`, so you can't use `append` on it.

```
>>> d = dict.fromkeys('abc')
>>> d
{'a': None, 'c': None, 'b': None}
```

---

A better solution will be to use `collections.defaultdict` here, in case that is not an option then use a normal `dict` with either a simple if-else check or `dict.setdefault`.

---

In Python3 `.keys()` returns a View Object, so time complexity may differ there. But, it is still going to be slightly slower than normal `key in dict` search.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at the `defaultdict` container to avoid checks

```
from collections import defaultdict

allnames [.... list of all the names ...]
codelist = defaultdict(list)

for row in rows:

    name,code = well.split()
    codelist[name].append(code)
```